# How to sync file sytem of OMV (OpenMediaVault) with Owncloud database

Tags: bash, file, synchronization, owncloud

I am running debian with OMV (Openmediavault) and Owncloud setup. I would like to sync the filesystem tree with the database of Owncloud. Because OMV can alter the files without Owncloud updating the database. I was thinking about a bash script.

When I Create delete or move a file it needs to be registered in the database of Owncloud.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little script I created for this purpose.
You will need the Inotify package.

```
#!/bin/sh
DATADIR="/sharedfolders/Owncloud"
inotifywait -m -r -q -e moved_to,create,delete --format '%w%f' "$DATADIR" |
while read INOTIFYFILE ; do # wait until change is made in the data dir
SCANFILE="${INOTIFYFILE##$DATADIR}" # converting Inotify output to something the owncloud --path option understands 
sudo -u www-data php /var/www/owncloud/occ files:scan --path="$SCANFILE" #remove -q to enable logging & scans detected file
done
```